# imported .mdx files does not get styles for inline-code and code previews

Tags: mdxjs

I ran into a problem / bug, when you import `.mdx` file inside another `.mdx` file, then imported file does not get styles for `inline-code` and `code` preview.

Text is displayed, also headings are formatted but styles for these 2 specific things are not.

What I mean by that is this:

**File1**

```
//File1.docs.mdx
import File2 from './file2.docs.mdx';

# Some heading in File1

Some text1

<File2 />
```

**File2**

````
//File2.docs.mdx

## Some heading in File2

Some `inline-code` preview in File2

```js
Some code preview in File2
```
````

Here is picture, with output. As you can see, text is correctly placed between `<code>` tags, but there is no class / style, which is supposed to style this preview.
[image]

This problem happens only in imported file (`File2`), while in `File1` everything works just fine.

Have you ever encountered this kind of problem?

I'm using `@mdx-js/loader: "~2.0.0"`